# What is the proper format for a StubHub JSON post request?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```js
{  
   "listing":{  
      "deliveryOption":"option",
      "event":{  
         "date":"date",
         "name":"name of event",
         "venue":"venue"
      },
      "externalListingId":"000000000",
      "inhandDate":"inhand date",
      "pricePerTicket":{  
         "amount":"cost",
         "currency":"USD"
      },
      "quantity":4,
      "rows":"row",
      "section":"sec",
      "splitOption":"MULTIPLES",
      "splitQuantity":[  
         2,
         4
      ]
   }
}
```

when sending post request with this json data, the response is:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_ARRAY token
```

if I leave out the `splitQuantity` key & value, it works.
is there something wrong with the JSON format?

The [documentation](https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/doc-viewer.jag?category=Listings&api=ListingAPI&endpoint=updatelistings) states:

`splitOption`: (string) `MULTIPLES`
`splitQuantity`: (int)  1, 2, 3, or a divisor of quantity (if quantity is 10, splitQuantity can be 1, 2, 3, 5, or 10).

Comment: The JSON is valid, but the does not mean it is valid data for the receiving application.

Comment: So what does the API documentation say is a valid object to pass in for that key? Perhaps a list of integers is not valid? This is not a Python or JSON question, really.

Comment: i'll post some of the documentation.

Comment: → HTTP Request 
Command: POST
URI template: /inventory/listings/v1
Authorization: Bearer {userToken}
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: 'splitOption: MULTIPLES'
'splitQuantity: 1, 2, 3, or a divisor of quantity'
its stubhubs listing tickets api...

Comment: @marcustrenton: you can [edit] your question to add more information. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/doc-viewer.jag?category=Listings&api=ListingAPI&endpoint=updatelistings you mean? Nowhere does it say that that property takes a list. It takes **one** integer only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [StubHub listing API documentation](https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/doc-viewer.jag?category=Listings&api=ListingAPI&endpoint=updatelistings), the `splitQuantity` value *must* be an integer. You set it to a *list* of integers, that is not a valid value for that key.

Set it to *one* integer instead. Because your `quantity` value is set to `4`, legal `splitQuantity` values are `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`:

```
"splitQuantity": 4,
```